# Apache2/PHP no longer logging errors after deleting error.log

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, php

I deleted error.log file from my logs directory.

As `root`, I used `vi` to create error.log file again. `root:root` owns the file, permissions are `-rw-r--r--`. Same ownership and permissions as access.log.

Now, no errors are being recorded. Access.log is still being appended to, but not error.log.

Any ideas?

PHP configured to log notices, warnings, errors. I'm using `error_log()` to trigger error messages as well, but with no luck. *Was* working up until I removed the log file.

PHP 5.3.10
Apache 2.2.22
Ubuntu 3.11

Comment: Delete file, then run `apache2ctl graceful`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apache process has an open file descriptor for its log files. If you delete one of them the corresponding file descriptor renders invalid and Apache stops logging. Next time, if you need to empty the log file without restarting Apache you can issue:

```
# echo > /var/log/apache/access.log
```

The file will be truncated but Apache won't stop logging.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I feel foolish. I guess all I needed was to restart the service with the file restored.

`service apache2 restart`

Comment: You don't need to restore the file, simple restart is enough.